Why multisig transaction has OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY as first opcode?
48490a078c7909194ddb995885b661b7513e9af05af66d2369190a2d983da3ee
I'm trying to understand why here is the OP_PUSHBYTES_32  OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY as first operation, does it work like 1-of-1 and 6-of-9 multisig? What is the reason for this?
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 3247347a997cac1b91c796b896ae85c2185fed60431ff98b4ad789f215929a1c
OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 23b29f89b45f4af41588dcaf0ca572ada32872a88224f311373917f1b37d08d1
OP_CHECKSIG
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 4b15848e495a3a62283daaadb3f458a00859fe48e321f0121ebabbdd6698f9fa
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 8242640732773249312c47ca7bdb50ca79f15f2ecc32b9c83ceebba44fb74df7
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 cbdd028cfe32c1c1f2d84bfec71e19f92df509bba7b8ad31ca6c1a134fe09204
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 d3c79b99ac4d265c2f97ac11e3232c07a598b020cf56c6f055472c893c0967ae
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 d45c70d28f169e1f0c7f4a78e2bc73497afe585b70aa897955989068f3350aaa
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 de13fc96ea6899acbdc5db3afaa683f62fe35b60ff6eb723dad28a11d2b12f8c
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 e36200aaa8dce9453567bba108bdc51f7f1174b97a65e4dc4402fc5de779d41c
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 f178fcce82f95c524b53b077e6180bd2d779a9057fdff4255a0af95af918cee0
OP_CHECKSIGADD
OP_PUSHNUM_6
OP_NUMEQUAL



does it work like 1-of-1 and 6-of-9 multisig?

Yes, it appears so.

What is the reason for this?

There is nothing we can infer from the transaction except for the fact that it is implementing an A and 6-out-of(B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J) policy (where the letters refer to the 10 keys in the script).
If you want to know the intent, you will have to find and ask the author of the transaction.
